# Riley Reddit - Music Edition

Tags: riddle, knowledge, music, affix-riddle

A redditor named [u/stanley_tweed](https://www.reddit.com/user/stanley_tweed) posted this [request](https://www.reddit.com/r/NameThatSong/comments/jhlvmv/an_actiony_upbeat_orchestral_instrumental_from_a/) to identify a certain song. I happen to know the song, so I decided it would be nice to make a Riley Riddle out of it.

According to his post:

- the song is an action-y upbeat orchestral instrumental from a musical (I'd say this  statement is [r/technicallythetruth](https://www.reddit.com/r/technicallythetruth))
- (redacted useless information)
- he thinks it's from a musical but suggests may be from a movie or something (it *is a* "musical", but not the Broadway-level you expect)
- he claims he doesn't know why or how he got this on his drive (The metadata of the audio file suggests a recent date, but as far as I know, the song is more than a decade old)

[Here](https://gofile.io/d/s6ZY4A) is the link to the audio file; now on to this Riley Riddle referring to the title of the song:

*'The' is the first and 'of' is the fourth*

*Second and penultimate is the stem thereof*

*The third is a grisly confrontation of the last*

*The entirety is a legendary battle of gods past*

**What is the title of the song?**

*Meta*: Assuming you know the song in the first place, it is 60%-80% possible to solve this puzzle by listening to the audio file alone, and 50%-70% by solving the Riley Riddle alone. If you don't know the song in the first place, then it is only 40%-60% by solving the Riley Riddle alone, and 20%-40% by listening to the audio file alone.

Clue (NSFW warning) [The answer doesn't have NSFW content, but something related does]:

> There exists a parody whose title can be solved by the following Riley Riddle:
>  
>  
>  *The first two and fourth are still the same,*
>  
>  *But the middle one is filled with all that came*
>  
>  *Making love, not war, the name of the game -*
>  
>  *Only the last comes to mind when swinging all the same*

Answer (score 3):

As weird as this particular version of the song might be (in particular, the chorus), it's got to be:

'The' is the first and 'of' is the fourth

> Placement of the words, straightforwardly.

Second and penultimate is the stem thereof

> They're both "ultimate" - which is the stem of "penultimate".

The third is a grisly confrontation of the last

> "showdown" (grisly confrontation) of "destiny"

The entirety is a legendary battle of gods past

> it's The Ultimate Showdown of Ultimate Destiny!

Comment: Good guys, bad guys, and explosions as far as the eye can see

Answer (score 0):

[Braegh](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/52963/braegh) already posted the answer, but I want to add some details:

- the song is an action-y upbeat orchestral instrumental

> The song is a cover of the original pop/rock song by Lemon Demon, an indie solo/band

- he thinks it's from a musical

> The music video, at least, is a musical according to one definition in Merriam-Webster.
>
>  It's got:

- > a film
- > a sentimental or humorous nature
- > musical numbers and dialogue
- > a unifying plot
- suggests may be from a movie or something

> Videos and animation embedded in Adobe Flash were called [Flash] movies

And for the final clue (NSFW warning):

> It is "The Ultimate Orgy of Homosexuality"